# Automatically reconnect Windows to Wifi

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

I have an industrial setup with Windows 10 pro connected to wifi as preferable network lets say to subnet 10.0.0.x . The automatically connect checkbox is set. However there is an UDP device connected to the ehthernet port of the computer. That setup is ideal from the security standpoint as the device is not visible on the commont network and only exists on the subnet controlled by Windows computer which is 192.168.0.x.

However when wifi goes down Windows apparently thinks that the ethernet network is a legitimate network and connects to it so it does not reconnect to wifi when the signals reappears. The setup is far away and I have to spend a lot of time driving there every time this happens.
Is there a way to make Windows to reconnect automatically to wifi even if there is a device on its ethernet subnet ?

Comment: In the advance TCP/IP properties of the Network Adapter, set the priority of the wireless card to be higher by giving it a lower Metric than the wired connection. That should work.

Comment: Yes it is there. When the computer reboots it does connect wifi first. However if wifi goes temporarly down it connects to ethernet ( I assume ) and never goes back to wifi

Comment: The nature of the wired device (not true TCP/IP) may prevent this. Can you connect it by Ethernet instead?  It seems more critical that it be connected).